# Exchangelib - How do i know if account has administrative rights?

Tags: python, exchangelib

I believe the question subject explains what i'm trying to achieve. i intend build an app that is wrapped around the python microsoft exchange library and i would like to display different options to the user depending on whether they have administrative rights or not.

Is there any function or workaround that can help me detect this?

thanks

Comment: I don't think this information is available via EWS, so you'll not be able find out via exchangelib either.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Just to know, are there any functions in exchnagelib/EWS that requires admin privilege to work?

Comment: I don't know. I would suggest either opening a new question for this specific topic, or asking in an EWS-specific forum.